# NSBundle creates files for given path

Tags: ios, nsbundle

When I use 
`NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"sqlite"];`

The NSBundle class, instead of returning nil, for a given file name when the file is not included in Xcode, seems to be creating the file no matter what. I tried removing file from xcode, it did not work, then I went to the path for simulator for the project (that path is generated by pathForResource) :

> /Users/USER_NAME/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhoneSimulator/6.0/Applications/APP_CODE/APP_NAME.app/sampleDB.sqlite

Before I run program in the debugger, I delete file "sampleDB.sqlite" manually. Every time the method pathForResource is called the file seems to magically reappear in the folder.

The documentation states : 
Return type :
The full pathname for the resource file or nil if the file could not be located.

EDIT:

With a pathForResource commented out, files removed - I still get that file magically reappearing in the bundle. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a clean build to make sure that the file gets removed from the app bundle.